# Amazon MWS Products SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: amazon-mws

When I run this code, I get a SignatureDoesNotMatch error. I'm not finding the issue. I even commented out the sort() to keep the array in natural order. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    $params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => "*********",
    'Action' => "GetCompetitivePricingForASIN",
    'SellerId' => "********",
    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
    'Timestamp' => gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
    'Version' => "2011-10-01",
    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
    'MarketplaceId' => "ATVPDKIKX0DER",
    'AsinList.ASIN.1' => $asin


    );

    $url_parts = array();
    foreach (array_keys($params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));
    //sort($url_parts);
    $url_string     = implode("&", $url_parts);
    $string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/Products/2011-10-01\n" .     $url_string;
    $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);
    $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
    $url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-10-01" . '?' . $url_string .  "&Signature=" . $signature;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $xml      = simplexml_load_string($response);

    echo $xml->asXML();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, took me 2 days to realize that

```
 $string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/Products/2011-10-01\n"
```

and

```
 $url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2011-10-01" . '?' . $url_string
```

just won't work together. Products and Orders aren't quite the same thing. Thanks for everyone's help. Rookie mistake here.

Answer (score 4):

Signature mismatch is a very common error and  diffcult to figure out the exact mistake as well!!.  My personal suggestion would be to compare the request with the Amazon scratchpad request. That has always helped in my case. And params has to be alphabetical order for the signature to match. 
Try your API request here :https://mws.amazonservices.in/scratchpad/index.html
And click on request details tab to see your full request url, signature, md5 hash etc.

Comment: This scratchpad does help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This cost me a few hours and I hope this may help anyone running into simple but less obvious causes for the SignatureDoesNotMatch error.

When the method required for the call is POST, be sure to specify that method in both the generated signature string and curl options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Comment: This solved my issue. I had a SignatureDoesNotMatch and could not figure it out. I was using code from a GET and forgot to update the curl settings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It took me the entire afternoon to figure out how to make it work. As @Bck said, it is difficult to figure out what's wrong.

Here are the mistakes I made:

1. I used the sample code in http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_SigningQueryRequest.html to sign my request. Be careful because its default url is actually mws.amazonservices.com/, but mine should mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01.
2. There is a slash in my private key, so when I selected it using double click, it just select the part before the slash. Make sure you do select the entire string when you try to copy/paste your key.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting a SignatureDoesNotMatch error, for me it turned out that I was double encoding the URL query string parameters.